# No database providers are configured. Identity and EF7

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

**This is different than other questions!**

`There was an error running the selected code generator:
'No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.'`

This error showed up while adding another database to my project. Before this, my project worked fine with ASP.NET Identity 3.

Now I have two databases, a custom one:

```
public class ShopDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; } 

    public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<ShopDbContext> options) : base (options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Follow the default behaviour of SqlServer for Identity Columns (Auto Increment)
        modelBuilder.ForSqlServerUseIdentityColumns();
    }
}
```

and the Identity one:

```
public class UsersDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UsersDbContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ForSqlServerToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ForSqlServerToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ForSqlServerToTable("Roles");
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConnections:Identity"]))
        .AddDbContext<ShopDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConnections:Shop"]));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // IoC Container
    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<UsersDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient<ShopDbContext>();
}
```

**Now the weird thing is that `ShopDbContext` works fine but `UsersDbContext` gives that error.**

Also the thing I did with the `ShopDbContext`'s constructor is not possible with the Identity one.

**EDIT:**

Here's the stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseProviderSelector.SelectServices(ServiceProviderSource providerSource)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Initialize>b__0()
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.get_DatabaseProviderServices()
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.GetProviderServices(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddEntityFramework>b__0_11(IServiceProvider p)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryService.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
DigitalShop.Models.Db.UsersDbContext..ctor() in UsersDbContext.cs
namespace DigitalShop.Models.Db
{
    public class UsersDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public UsersDbContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated(); // <-- Error
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

**EDIT 2:**

If I change the `UsersDbContext` to also override the `OnConfiguring` method, from there it actually creates the database and it works (even if I don't remove the lines from `Startup.cs` and are supposed to do this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DigitalShop_Identity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
}
```

**Now the question in why is setting the connection string from `Startup.cs` not working?**

**EDIT 3:**

During debugging the `UsersDbContext` I noticed that `OnConfiguring` method runs before the constructor! I think that's why It never executes `Database.EnsureCreated();` and therefore throws exception. How is that possible??

Comment: Please add error and show *IdentityDbContext*.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Show it?

Comment: Sorry for *IdentityDbContext*.  I was referring to a message. *Stack trace* - it is good, but what is error message?

Comment: @DenisBubnov, The title of this question is the error message!

Comment: It's not me. I follow the question. I did not use EF7 and I'm interested in the question. I upvote for you

Comment: Got the same issue - any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @PhilAI Gave up on Identity and now using the built-in ASP.NET Core Authorization. It just works.